# Webview and loadurl call in another class

Tags: java, javascript, android, webview

I'm having some troubles calling webView.loadUrl from javascriptInterface:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.webkit.JavascriptInterface;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.content.Intent;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private WebView webView;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);

        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        JavaScriptInterface jsInterface = new JavaScriptInterface(this);

        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        webView.addJavascriptInterface(jsInterface, "JSInterface");

        webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());


        webView.loadUrl("http://*****.com/test.php");

    }

    public class JavaScriptInterface {
        private Activity activity;

        public JavaScriptInterface(Activity activiy) {
            this.activity = activiy;
        }

        @JavascriptInterface
        public void changeTest(){
            webView.loadUrl("http://google.it");
        }
    }

}
```

First loadUrl(), the one in onCreate, success, but the other called in JavascriptsInterface fails. However changeTest() runs for sure when I call it from page via Javascript because I used to call an app via intent and it loaded fine. So the problem have to be with loadUrl placed externally from onCreate.
Could someone explain what is wrong and how come?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually you can as it worked for me with slight modification. Please make sure to run the code in the UI Thread.

```
        @JavascriptInterface
        public void changeTest(){

            Log.d("TEST", "THIS IS THE BIGGEST TEST EVER");

            activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    myWebView.loadUrl("http://google.it");
                }
            });
        }
```

Here is an excerpt of the Javascript function written in my html page:

```
function doChangeTest(){
        //JSInterface is the supplied name of the interface
        // in Android code: webView.addJavascriptInterface(jsInterface, "JSInterface");
        JSInterface.changeTest();
}
```